# Magento 1.9.2.1 - Observer: catalog_product_save_before doesn't fire

Tags: php, events, magento-1.9, observers

I have searched I don't know how many Google pages before deciding to write this question and I know there is a already some very nice answers from [Marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2047249/marius) and [Alan Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4668/alan-storm) to very similar questions but I unfortunately haven't been able to demystify why my observer doesn't fire as it should.

It is not the first time I'm playing with observers and I have flushed the cache either from admin and manually the var/cache folder, I have tried different working syntaxes to call the model (complete_model_path_with underscores,module/model,uppercase, lowercase). I have other observers working fine everyday on the same install and I tried to do it the exact same way without success. I have also tried to call with singleton instead of model. I have tried the three scope views (global, frontend and adminhtml). I have searched for any direct or indirect core overwrite, it is still possible that I would have missed one hidden inside an other module but I almost always use modules from well known developpers who respect most of Magento standards.

**There is part of my code:**

app/code/local/NameSpace/Module/etc/**config.xml**

```
<global>
  <models>
    <module>
      <class>NameSpace_Module_Model</class>
      <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </module>
  </models>
  <events>
    <catalog_product_save_before>
      <observers>
        <module>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>NameSpace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>catalogProductSaveBefore</method>
        </module>
      </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_before>
  </events>
</global>
```

app/code/local/NameSpace/Module/Model/**Observer.php**

```
class NameSpace_Module_Model_Observer
{   

    public function catalogProductSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        file_put_contents("OBSERVER.TXT","FIRED");
        echo "hello";
        exit();

        return $this;
    }

}
```

---

### UPDATE

app/etc/modules/**NameSpace_Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <NameSpace_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
      <depends>
          <Mage_Catalog />
      </depends>
    </NameSpace_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

---

I even tried to add random caracters in the code to provoque a fatal error but it is never called. It could be a very simple mistake of mine, all I know is that I carefully overlooked my code and I can't seem to find the issue.

**Please try to comment before giving an answer as I already tried many solutions and maybe yours already.**

Thank you very much in advance for your help, **any suggestion will be appreciated!**

Comment: have you tried using a debugger? did you try creating a module for it? if you did, where did you save the module manifest?

Comment: @iam-decoder thank you for your comment. I haven't try any debugger, would you suggest one? This observer is actully part of a fully functionnal and working module, from my knowledge it has to be to work. I'm sorry but I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "manifest"?

Comment: [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) has done well for me over the years, and the manifest is the module's XML file. since your module is working, did you follow along with the module's folder structure? It's hard to tell easily without that XML piece

Comment: **Do you mean this file:** _app/etc/modules/NameSpace_Module.xml_ ?

Comment: yes, it has a folder structure that needs to be followed in order for the module to control actions there. Don't know if you've already given this a good read but it may help you [Ash Smith - Making use of Observers in Magento](https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/)

Comment: I have updated the question and added the module XML file content to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some moments where I am asking myself;

> -Am I really a developer?

These moments where all of my complex code is verified and fully functionnal in all possible ways except something so basic and small.

**After verifying if my observer model really exists inside of Magento:**

```
require_once('/home/user/public_html/app/Mage.php');

Mage::init();

$observer = Mage::getModel('module/observer');
```

It does, I also realised that the output was simple ***text***...

#### Adding `<?php` before any php code is always a good idea!